# VirtualBox - unable to access host web server with guest browser

Tags: mac, virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox with Win7 guest VM on a Mac OSX 10.9.x host.  I can access the Internet from a browser on the guest vm (used same proxy as host's in browser's proxy settings).  I can also ping the host's IP address from the command line on the guest.

I have a web server running from the host, but no matter what address type I use in the guest's browser URL, I always get a Gateway Timeout (504 error). I've tried the following:

> http:// l o c a l h o s t :port /  OR
>   http:// i p a d d r e s s - o f - h o s t :port /

I've tried the following instructions at [this link](http://justinmarsan.com/accessing-localhost-in-mac-osx-from-windows-vm-in-virtualbox/) but still continue to get the same gateway timeout error.

Any inputs would help, thanks.

Comment: remove the proxy settings you set in the VM and try it again -- your proxy and/or internet-facing router may not allow the web requests to flow back into the LAN.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it depends on how you set-up the website on the host but you can try the following. In the Windows VM settings enable 1 network adapter and set it to NAT. Try to connect to the host by using this IP: http://10.0.2.2

Worked for me on OS X 10.10.

If you have set-up virtual hosts on your Host machine then in the VM edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add a line similar to this:

```
10.0.2.2  virtual-host-name
```

Note: because Windows doesn't allow you to make edits to the hosts file by default you might need to make a copy of the hosts file to the VM desktop first. Make your edits there and copy the hosts file back overwriting the original file.